# How to create a empty temporary table from another tables schema?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there an idiomatic way of doing this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
select * into x_temp from tbl where 1 = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

This works in most DBs:

```
create table blah as
select * from foo where 1=0
```

Note that this will not copy PKs, indexes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
select top 0 * into temp_table from table
```

This is what I typically use, but I like Michael B's method too.